# How to reason about stack safety in Scala Cats / fs2?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, tail-recursion, scala-cats, fs2

Here is a piece of code from the documentation for [fs2](https://fs2.io/guide.html). The function `go` is recursive. The question is **how do we know if it is stack safe and how to reason if any function is stack safe?**

```
import fs2._
// import fs2._

def tk[F[_],O](n: Long): Pipe[F,O,O] = {
  def go(s: Stream[F,O], n: Long): Pull[F,O,Unit] = {
    s.pull.uncons.flatMap {
      case Some((hd,tl)) =>
        hd.size match {
          case m if m <= n => Pull.output(hd) >> go(tl, n - m)
          case m => Pull.output(hd.take(n.toInt)) >> Pull.done
        }
      case None => Pull.done
    }
  }
  in => go(in,n).stream
}
// tk: [F[_], O](n: Long)fs2.Pipe[F,O,O]

Stream(1,2,3,4).through(tk(2)).toList
// res33: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

Would it also be stack safe if we call `go` from another method?

```
def tk[F[_],O](n: Long): Pipe[F,O,O] = {
  def go(s: Stream[F,O], n: Long): Pull[F,O,Unit] = {
    s.pull.uncons.flatMap {
      case Some((hd,tl)) =>
        hd.size match {
          case m if m <= n => otherMethod(...)
          case m => Pull.output(hd.take(n.toInt)) >> Pull.done
        }
      case None => Pull.done
    }
  }

  def otherMethod(...) = {
    Pull.output(hd) >> go(tl, n - m)
  }

  in => go(in,n).stream
}
```

Comment: No, not exactly. Although if this is the case of tail recursion please tell so, but it seems that it's not.
As far as I know cats does some magic called trampolining to ensure stack safety. Unfortunately I cannot tell when a function is trampolined and when not.

Comment: You can rewrite `go` to use e.g. `Monad[F]` typeclass - there is `tailRecM` method allowing you to perform trampoline explicitly to guarantee that the function would be stack safe. I might be wrong but without it you are relying on `F` being stack safe on its own (e.g. if it implements trampoline internally), but you never know who will define your `F`, so you shouldn't do this. If you have no guarantee that `F` is stack safe, use a type class which provides `tailRecM` because it is stack-safe by law.

Comment: It's easy to let compiler prove it with `@tailrec` annotation for tail rec functions. For other cases there are no formal guarantees in Scala AFAIK. Even if the function itself is safe, the other functions it's calling might not be :/.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54492892/334519) gives some background information that might be useful. The basic idea is that some effect types have `flatMap` implementations that support stack-safe recursion directly—you can nest `flatMap` calls either explicitly or through recursion as deeply as you want and you won't overflow the stack.

For some effect types it's not possible for `flatMap` to be stack-safe, because of the semantics of the effect. In other cases it may be possible to write a stack-safe `flatMap`, but the implementers might have decided not to because of performance or other considerations.

Unfortunately there's no standard (or even conventional) way to know whether the `flatMap` for a given type is stack-safe. Cats does include a `tailRecM` operation that should provide stack-safe monadic recursion for any lawful monadic effect type, and sometimes looking at a `tailRecM` implementation that's known to be lawful can provide some hints about whether a `flatMap` is stack-safe. In the case of `Pull` it looks like [this](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2/blob/5a9283fa30dde2cbf6e19a0c14a92ad88e7eb034/core/shared/src/main/scala/fs2/Pull.scala#L177):

```
def tailRecM[A, B](a: A)(f: A => Pull[F, O, Either[A, B]]) =
  f(a).flatMap {
    case Left(a)  => tailRecM(a)(f)
    case Right(b) => Pull.pure(b)
  }
```

This `tailRecM` is just recursing through `flatMap`, and we know that `Pull`'s `Monad` instance [is lawful](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2/blob/5a9283fa30dde2cbf6e19a0c14a92ad88e7eb034/core/shared/src/test/scala/fs2/PullLawsSpec.scala#L40), which is pretty good evidence that `Pull`'s `flatMap` is stack-safe. The one complicating factor here is that the instance for `Pull` has an `ApplicativeError` constraint on `F` that `Pull`'s `flatMap` doesn't, but in this case that doesn't change anything.

So the `tk` implementation here is stack-safe because `flatMap` on `Pull` is stack-safe, and we know that from looking at its `tailRecM` implementation. (If we dug a little deeper we could figure out that `flatMap` is stack-safe because `Pull` is essentially a wrapper for `FreeC`, which is [trampolined](http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/stackless-scala-with-free-monads.html).)

It probably wouldn't be terribly hard to rewrite `tk` in terms of `tailRecM`, although we'd have to add the otherwise unnecessary `ApplicativeError` constraint. I'm guessing the authors of the documentation chose not to do that for clarity, and because they knew `Pull`'s `flatMap` is fine.

---

Update: here's a fairly mechanical `tailRecM` translation:

```
import cats.ApplicativeError
import fs2._

def tk[F[_], O](n: Long)(implicit F: ApplicativeError[F, Throwable]): Pipe[F, O, O] =
  in => Pull.syncInstance[F, O].tailRecM((in, n)) {
    case (s, n) => s.pull.uncons.flatMap {
      case Some((hd, tl)) =>
        hd.size match {
          case m if m <= n => Pull.output(hd).as(Left((tl, n - m)))
          case m => Pull.output(hd.take(n.toInt)).as(Right(()))
        }
      case None => Pull.pure(Right(()))
    }
  }.stream
```

Note that there's no explicit recursion.

---

The answer to your second question depends on what the other method looks like, but in the case of your specific example, `>>` will just result in more `flatMap` layers, so it should be fine.

To address your question more generally, this whole topic is a confusing mess in Scala. You shouldn't have to dig into implementations like we did above just to know whether a type supports stack-safe monadic recursion or not. Better conventions around documentation would be a help here, but unfortunately we're not doing a very good job of that. You could always use `tailRecM` to be "safe" (which is what you'll want to do when the `F[_]` is generic, anyway), but even then you're trusting that the `Monad` implementation is lawful.

To sum up: it's a bad situation all around, and in sensitive situations you should definitely write your own tests to verify that implementations like this are stack-safe.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. 
Regarding the question when we call `go` from another method, what can make it stack unsafe? 
If we do some non-recursive calculations before we call 
`Pull.output(hd) >> go(tl, n - m)` is it fine?

Comment: Yes, that should be fine (assuming the calculation itself doesn't overflow the stack, of course).

Comment: Which effect type, for instance, wouldn't be stack-safe for monadic recursion? The continuation type?

Comment: @bob Right, although Cats's `ContT`'s `flatMap` _is_ actually stack-safe (via a `Defer` constraint on the underlying type). I was thinking more of something like `List`, where recursing through `flatMap` isn't stack-safe (it does have a lawful `tailRecM`, though).